# How do I change the color of a certain button in ActionSheet?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet

```
var sheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet()
        sheet.title  = "Report this member?"
        sheet.delegate = self
        sheet.tag = 1
        sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
        sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Report")
        sheet.cancelButtonIndex = 0
        sheet.showInView(self.view)
```

I want "report" to be red, and cancel to be grey.

Is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: I am wondering that why you are using UIActionSheet? It is deprecated in iOS 8. Why don't you go with UIAlertController https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

Comment: As Soil said above, it'd be best to go with UIAlertController - you add UIAlertActions as buttons, and I'm almost positive you could override it. A simple search for "UIAlertAction Color" would probably give you the desired effects.

Comment: One work around, just set the index of the Report button as your destructive button: `sheet.destructiveButtonIndex=1` and iOS will highlight is as red because it's declared as a critical action.  Note: Apple may decide to change this in the future to some other visual indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve this, create customized buttons, add them as **subview**

```
var sheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet()
sheet.title  = "Report this member?"

var btn:UIButton = UIButton()
btn.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
btn.addTarget(self, action: "pressCancel", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
sheet.addSubview(btn)

var btn1:UIButton = UIButton()
btn1.setTitle("Report", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn1.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
btn1.addTarget(self, action: "pressReport", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
sheet.addSubview(btn1)
```